# How to save a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, save

I have a javascript variable, which is incremented by a javascript function in a .php script, only problem is that the page reloads when the function is called, so I need some way of saving the variable to be the same when the page is either reloaded or whenever you enter it. 
I know you can do a local save but I am not quiet sure if it saves the variable when you leave the website.

My variable is in a html script.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

                    var varNumber= 1;
                    document.getElementById("varNumber").innerHTML = varNumber;
                    document.getElementByID("varNumber").value = varNumber;


                    function addToVariable() {
                        varNumber= varNumber+ 1 ;
                        document.getElementById("varNumber").innerHTML = varNumber;
                    }

                </script>
```

Comment: is it global for the server or global per person?

Comment: Have you looked into cookies?

Comment: then you can use cache :)

Comment: You should use `$_SESSION` with PHP. JavaScript will load all the code again every time the page loads. JavaScript supports `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` in newer Browsers. Depending on how the page is reloading you could also use `location.hash` or `location.search` to get a value from a URL, as well.

Comment: $_SESSION is not suitable because in every request create it's own session...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three client-side methods to save JavaScript variables across page refreshes and descriptions on how long they can persist data.

### Saving a JavaScript variable with local storage

Saving a JS variable using local storage is easy and convenient with modern browsers.

```
var get = function (key) {
  return window.localStorage ? window.localStorage[key] : null;
}

var put = function (key, value) {
  if (window.localStorage) {
    window.localStorage[key] = value;
  }
}
```

To save and read an object instead of a simple variable:

```
localStorage.yourObject = JSON.stringify(obj);

obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.yourObject || "{}");
```

**Persistence:**

> User agents may, if so configured by the user, automatically delete
>   stored data after a period of time.
>
> For example, a user agent could be configured to treat third-party
>   local storage areas as session-only storage, deleting the data once
>   the user had closed all the browsing contexts that could access it.
>
> This can restrict the ability of a site to track a user, as the site
>   would then only be able to track the user across multiple sessions
>   when he authenticates with the site itself (e.g. by making a purchase
>   or logging in to a service).
>
> However, this also reduces the usefulness of the API as a long-term
>   storage mechanism. It can also put the user's data at risk, if the
>   user does not fully understand the implications of data expiration.

References:

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/
- [Persisting values in JavaScript object across browser refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127498/persisting-values-in-javascript-object-across-browser-refresh)
- [How persistent is localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage)

---

### Saving a JavaScript variable with cookies

Saving a variable with cookies:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Persistence:**

> Session cookies - these are temporary and are erased when you close
>   your browser at the end of your session.
>
> Persistent cookies - these remain on the client hard drive until they
>   are erased or expire.
>
> This is ultimately user-dependent. They could be paranoid about
>   cookies and local storage, and set them to session-only or none at
>   all.

REF: [Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

---

### Saving a JavaScript variable with `window.name`

You could also use the window’s name `window.name` to store the information using a [JavaScript session](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html).

**Persistence:**

> This only works as long as the same window/tab is used.

REF: http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html

Comment: If I choose to use the local storage will it save the variable and keep even though the website is reloaded or reentered?

Comment: Usually, but it's ultimately user-dependent. They could be paranoid about cookies and local storage and set them to session-only.

Comment: @DevLiv Hello, was this answer able to help you with your issue? What were you able to implement in your solution?

Comment: yes it helped me on the way  to figure out what I needed for my function, I ended up using a server side save, but this helped me on the way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can use localStorage on client side

```
<script>
  localStorage.setItem("mykey",99); // set a variable

  var varNumber = localStorage.getItem("mykey"); // retrieve variable
</script>
```

Comment: Some reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX to execute PHP, like:

```
<?php
session_start(); $r = array();
if(isset($_POST['holdNumber'])){ // assumes {holdNumber:numberHere} sent through AJAX
  if(preg_match('/^\d+$/', $_POST['holdNumber']){
    $r['heldNumber'] = $_SESSION['holdNumber'] = $_POST['holdNumber'];
  }
  else{
    // holdNumber hack
  }
}
elseif(isset($_POST['load'])){
  if(+$_POST['load'] === 1){ // assumes sending {load:1} in AJAX
    if(isset($_SESSION['holdNumber']){
      $r['heldNumber'] = $_SESSION['holdNumber'];
    }
    else{
      $r['heldNumber'] = $_SESSION['holdNumber'] = 0;
    }
  }
  else{
    // load hack
  }
}
echo json_encode($r);
?>
```

Comment: Will this save the variable when the website is reloaded?